# Segmentation Fault Using bsearch in C

Tags: c, pointers, fault, bsearch

```
player_t* getFirstMatch(player_t** sortedPlayers, int playerCount, char* inputString)
{
   player_t searchPlayer;
   player_t* searchPlayerPointer = &searchPlayer;

   searchPlayer.nameLast = inputString;

   searchPlayerPointer = (player_t*) bsearch(searchPlayerPointer, 
      *sortedPlayers, playerCount, sizeof(player_t*), 
      playerCompareLast);

   return searchPlayerPointer;
}
```

My program gets a segmentation fault on the line that uses bsearch(). What am I doing wrong here? Here is my comparison function. I was using a similar version for qsort, but now I need to use this one for bsearch :

```
int playerCompareLast(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  char* nameLast1;
  char* nameLast2;

  int result;

  nameLast1 = (*(player_t **)p1)->nameLast;
  nameLast2 = (*(player_t **)p2)->nameLast;

  result = strcmp(nameLast1, nameLast2);

  return result; 
}
```

The player_t type is just a Struct with a bunch of different members (like nameLast, nameFirst, etc.). I can't figure out what is wrong with my bsearch() arguments!

Comment: So much type casting going on.

Comment: How is `getFirstMatch` being called? You really need to check for Null pointers.

Comment: Why would `p1` and `p2` be a pointer to pointer type? Shouldn't `p1` and `p2` both be cast to `player_t *` type?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `bsearch` to search an array of pointers, apparently: the `base` argument is `player_t**` and the `size` argument is `sizeof(player_t*)`. The implementation of  `playerCompare` seems to match this, as it casts `p` to `player_t**`.

Alas, you are passing the key as `player_t*`, not as `player_t**`. To match the behavior of `playerCompare` your should pass `&playerPointer` (that is , `player_t**`).

I expect the access violation/seg fault to occur in `playerCompare` called by `bsearch` (including `strcmp` called from `playerCompare`), a quick inspection of the dump or a look in the debugger at the stack raising it should confirm.